# How to make front audio jack work again after waking up from suspend?

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa, suspend

Sometimes, after I wake up from suspend (using pm-suspend), the front audio jack stops working (no sound) after I wake up my laptop. Only after a full reboot I get it to work again.

My laptop is an HP dv6-2030sd and has an Intel sound card. The module loaded is snd_hda_intel, but removing it and adding it again has no effect. I use the ALSA sound system only, so no pulseaudio.

My question is, is there a way to get it to work again without a full reboot?

Comment: What does unloading then reloading the module do? Do you have that option?

Comment: In what sense? When unloaded, the sound stops working at all, when reloading it again, sound starts working again, but still no front audio.

Comment: Was hoping that worked, then you could write a custom load/unload script when waking from suspend. But alas it doesn't work. Something about the S1,S2,S3 may be broken in that bios, pretty typical of machines targeted for Windows.

Comment: Ok, so rebooting would be the only option.

Comment: Before giving up, check if there is an ALSA switch or mixer for front audio... you may just be able to turn it back on. Or maybe cycle the switch once. Check `amixer contents`.

Comment: @derobert: I believe I already have checked that to no prevail.

Comment: @derobert Checked again, there is nothing disabled. Result of amixer contents: https://gist.github.com/ffd9d9c1cc13c8ed00a6

Comment: @Ikke: I assume you tried toggling those mute switches? Also, which sound module does that laptop use—there are module parameters to `snd_hda_intel` that you can play with to see if they help. Same with some of the other modules. Also, when removing/adding try the entire stack—there are surely some codec modules as well. `lsmod | grep snd` will help find them.

Comment: @derobert I indeed toggled them. I'll try to remove the entire stack next time this problem occurs.